# Passing a class to Python's super()

Tags: python, oop

I have a class(call it ClassC) where one of the attributes is another class(call it ClassB). ClassB actually needs data from ClassC to initialize itself, so I pass ClassC to ClassB using the following syntax:

```
class ClassC(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.val = 8
    self.derived_class = ClassB(self)
```

I'm seeing an error that complains about init() not taking any parameters, but I'm just not seeing where the issue could be arising from. Am I not using super() in the correct way so that ClassB initializes its base class,ClassA, as well?

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "python", line 18, in
>      File "python", line 15, in **init**   File "python", line
>   9, in **init** TypeError: object.**init**() takes no parameters

I have reproduced the code below, or you can [run it here](https://repl.it/repls/AthleticSpiritedSyntax).

```
class ClassA(object):
  def __init__(self, initial_class):
    self.val = None
    self.initial_class = initial_class

class ClassB(ClassA):
  def __init__(self, initial_class):
    super(ClassA, self).__init__(initial_class)
    self.val = 7

class ClassC(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.val = 8
    self.derived_class = ClassB(self)

c = ClassC()
```

Comment: You're using `super` wrong. You have to change `super(ClassA, self)` to `super(ClassB, self)` (or just `super()` if you're using python 3). `super(ClassA, self)` gives you a proxy to the _parent class_ of `ClassA`, which is `object`.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Can you submit your answer?